# Use of "cynicism" in this sentence

Tags: meaning

The following is from the [NYTimes](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/20/opinion/nocera-911s-white-elephant.html).

> "What has been especially galling to me has been the *cynicism* surrounding the efforts to get the toll increases. First, the Port Authority said that unless it could increase the tolls, it would have to “slow or stop” the construction of 1 World Trade Center. Though this scenario was highly unlikely, it got the construction unions duly aroused, as it was intended to do. They began calling in favors among the politicians."

I've looked up the definition of *cynicism*, but could someone explain the definition in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Port Authority claims failure to raise tolls will result in construction stoppage. The author suggests that the Port Authority doesn't actually believe this, but knows that this claim will cause the unions (who don't work if the construction stops) to force politicians (whom the unions help elect) to raise the tolls. Assuming this is true, the Port Authority has achieved its end not by appealing directly to the general good, but by appealing to the special interests of the parties involved (the unions, who want to work, and the politicians, who want to remain in office) under the guise of appealing to the general good (continuing construction, which the author claims does not depend on raising the tolls).

It is this false pretense that the author considers cynical, as someone who believes in the primacy of the general good would not employ such a ruse, while a cynic would gladly do so.

Comment: When referring to actual pretense, one should say *pretense* or *falsity* or *falseness* rather than *false pretense*.

Answer (score 2):

"Cynicism" here has the meaning of :

> disparaging the motives of others.

The article makes the statement that "the efforts to increase the toll" is surrounded by the fact that some people are trying to disparage the motives of others. How?

By :

> unless it could increase the tolls, it would have to “slow or stop” the construction of 1 World Trade Center.

So, unless the construction of 1 World Trade Center "slows or stops", the toll cannot increase. The toll can only increase, at the expense of something else, namely, the construction of the World Trade Center. That's the cynicism surrounding the toll increase efforts.

I hope that explains it.